# YAML setting value from another key

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, swiftmailer

How can I set a value in YAML from another key e.g:

```
example.emails:
     - ben@example.co
     - neb@example.co
     - teb@example.co

swift:
        to_email:   example.emails
```

Comment: do you mean [relational tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Relational_trees)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ohh found the answer, just could not seem to find good documentation from Google :S

```
example.emails: 
     - ben@example.co 
     - neb@example.co 
     - teb@example.co 

swift: 
      to_email: "%example.emails%"
```

Comment: I can't tell what this answer actually means.  What do the percents (`%`) do?  Does this interpolate somehow?  A full example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is still really unclear to me. An additional example, an demonstration of the result, or a link to the docs where you figured this out would be great.

Comment: There is nothing in the YAML specification that describes that anything special needs to be done while/after loading this example. If PHP / Synfony does somethings special with `"%example.emails%"` that might be so, but that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: That won't work until `example.emails` is placed as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer is wrong. It might have worked for the author for app specific reason but it is not supported by YAML specs. The correct way to reuse values in yaml is through something called anchors, like this

```
x1: &my_anchor
  y: 'my val'
x2:
  <<: *my_anchor
  z: 3
```

In above, we mark the values in `x1` using anchor `my_anchor`. Then the special syntax `<<: *my_anchor` tells YAML parser to insert children of the node (in this case `y`) in the same level. So `x2` will now have two children: `y` and `z`.